# Inserting javascript in to html file

Tags: javascript, html

How can I run this script, tried to run it in html file, but it doesn't seem to work..

I want this code to be in single html file, is it possible? or do I need different files?
http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/jcnMa/1/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.question, .answer')
    .css("display", "none");
$('.section')
    .click(function ()
{
    var $others = $('.question:visible')
        .not(this);
    $others.next('.answer')
        .hide();
    $others.slideToggle(500);
    $(this)

        .next('.question')
        .slideToggle(500);
});
$('.question')
    .click(function ()
{
    $(this)
        .next('.answer')
        .slideToggle(500);
});​
</script>
```

Comment: Did you include the jQuery-Library is it is included in your jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure you're including the jQuery library:

```
<script src="path/to/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Make sure you're not including the jQuery within those tags, so you've got:

```
<script src="path/to/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    /* Your jQuery here */
</script>
```

And then ensure you're using a `$(document).ready()`, or `$(window).load()`, handler:

```
<script src="path/to/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(
        function(){
            /* Your jQuery here */
        });
</script>
```

The requirement for the `$(document).ready()` (or `$(window).load()`) is to ensure that the DOM is constructed, and the elements to which you want to bind events are present. Without those handlers the browser will try to bind events as soon as it encounters your script, without waiting for the elements to exist or be created, which results in non-functioning event-binding.

Comment: I prefer to load the script at the end of page insted of using $(document).ready

Comment: @hish: it's more or less irrelevant whichever way it's done, my personal preference is to insulate the JavaScript from future DOM-rearrangement and encapsulate within a DOM-ready (or window-load) event, in the event a future client, or developer, wants to move the script from one place to another. That said, I tend to start with my scripts in the `head` anyway, so they're required for my starting use-case.

Comment: as performance it is better to add the javescript at the end of file. so the script will not block the page load .

Comment: tryed to get exampkle from http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_slide_toggle and it worked out, but when i made multiple sections first one only worked

Comment: Then you need to very clearly articulate exactly what you mean by 'not working.' Any errors in your JavaScript console? Is jQuery being loaded (look at the network/resources tabs in your developer tools)?

Comment: uploaded my index file http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/372881/index-html.html browser just pops out like there where no query, but tryed different code to check if jquery.js is working, and different code worked

Comment: I'm not downloading your file, reproduce the problem (take out everything else that's not needed, leaving *only* what's needed to reproduce your problem) at an online demo site (such as JS Fiddle, or Codepen.io, or similar.

Comment: when i copy only html part, it shows symbols int he bottom of page

Answer (score 0):

put this code before the body close tag

```
Your Code 
</body>
```

Comment: yes because you select object from the dom so when this code execute you need to be sure that dom element exists . if they not exists it will return error .

Comment: at the header tag load the jquery library

Comment: jquery library... ok. :D not sure how to load it, and where to get that

Comment: <script src="jquery.js"></script>

Comment: did you download jquery.js file ?

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

I would go this way:

```
<head>
    ...
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.question, .answer').css("display", "none");
            $('.section').click(function ()
            {
                var $others = $('.question:visible').not(this);
                $others.next('.answer').hide();
                $others.slideToggle(500);
                $(this).next('.question').slideToggle(500);
            });
            $('.question').click(function ()
            {
                $(this).next('.answer').slideToggle(500);
            });​
        });
    </script>
    ...
</head>
```

First you need to ensure jquery lib is loaded, then you might notice that your code is referring to object in DOM, so you can access them only when the page is loaded (or after they are entered in the body code). I prefer to store my js code in the head section whenever it's possible.